# Hindi Contents are not displaying in ckeditor?

Tags: jsp, ckeditor

I am trying to display hindi contents in ckeditor on jsp page by following code-

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" ><%=fetchedContents%></textarea>
```

where `fetchedContents` is a String variable.  In it i am fetching hindi contents from a file(Velocity Template). But contents are displaying in ckeditor in following format-

```
à¤¶à¤ªà¤¥ à¤à¤¯ à¤à¤° à¤¬à¥à¤¬à¤¾à¤à¥ à¤ªà¥à¤°à¤®à¤¾à¤£ à¤ªà¤¤à¥à¤° 
à¤ªà¥à¤°à¤¾à¤ªà¥à¤¤ à¤à¤°à¤¨à¥ à¤à¥ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤à¤¯ à¤à¤°
```

is it problem of ckeditor or jsp page?
Please give me solution?

following are code which helps you for better understanding-

```
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.init(velocityProperties);
        Template t = ve.getTemplate( templateName );
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("fullname", fullname);
        context.put("fathername", fathername);    

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);

        String fetchedContents = writer.toString();
```

above code is written in servlet and by this servlet i am fetching `fetchedContents` on jsp

```
String fetchedContents = (String) session.getAttribute("fetchedContents");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can check if it's a cke issue by removing the name and id from the textare so that it does not get replaced by cke - then you check the normal textarea - if it contains that format, the issue is Not with ckeditor.

Comment: thanks. means it is problem with jsp page. then how could i solve this issue. i have tried to change page encoding on jsp page but haven't got success.

Comment: Have you set the jsp page encoding to `utf-8` ? `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened.

Comment: @user3811381 try setting the value to a fresh text area without `ckeditor` and see whether the letters are rendered properly in it. so that you can narrow your problem.